# Calculate an array of Moment.js Ranges found in one array but not in another

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs, moment-range

Given the 2 arrays `a` and `b` containing [moment ranges](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range),

```
const Moment = require('moment');
const MomentRange = require('moment-range');
const moment = MomentRange.extendMoment(Moment);

let a = [
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 09:00'), moment('2020-01-01 11:00')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 14:00'), moment('2020-01-01 18:00')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 20:00'), moment('2020-01-01 21:00')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 22:00'), moment('2020-01-01 23:00'))
];

let b = [
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 11:30'), moment('2020-01-01 13:00')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 17:00'), moment('2020-01-01 20:30')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 21:45'), moment('2020-01-01 23:15'))
];
```

How can we calculate an array `c` containing moment ranges that are found in `b` but not in `a`?

For an example involving `a` and `b`, we want to get the result `c`, given by

```
let c = [
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 11:30'), moment('2020-01-01 13:00')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 18:00'), moment('2020-01-01 20:00')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 21:45'), moment('2020-01-01 22:00')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 23:00'), moment('2020-01-01 23:15'))
];
```

Using node v14.2.0, `moment` 2.27.0 and `moment-range` 4.0.2.

---

@Nikita-Iskorkin Running your code

```
let c = [];
b.forEach(range => {
    if (!a.includes(range))
        c.push(range)
})
```

gives the following result for `c` which does not exclude/subtract away the time ranges found in `a`:

```
[
  t {
    start: Moment<2020-01-01T11:30:00-05:00>,
    end: Moment<2020-01-01T13:00:00-05:00>
  },
  t {
    start: Moment<2020-01-01T17:00:00-05:00>,
    end: Moment<2020-01-01T20:30:00-05:00>
  },
  t {
    start: Moment<2020-01-01T21:45:00-05:00>,
    end: Moment<2020-01-01T23:15:00-05:00>
  }
]
```

The desired result `c` should be:

```
[
  t {
    start: Moment<2020-01-01T11:30:00-05:00>,
    end: Moment<2020-01-01T13:00:00-05:00>
  },
  t {
    start: Moment<2020-01-01T18:00:00-05:00>,
    end: Moment<2020-01-01T20:00:00-05:00>
  },
  t {
    start: Moment<2020-01-01T21:45:00-05:00>,
    end: Moment<2020-01-01T22:00:00-05:00>
  },
  t {
    start: Moment<2020-01-01T23:00:00-05:00>,
    end: Moment<2020-01-01T23:15:00-05:00>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check in forEach-loop of array `b` that range doesn't contains in array `a` and push push it to `c`

```
const Moment = require('moment');
const MomentRange = require('moment-range');
const moment = MomentRange.extendMoment(Moment);

let a = [
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 09:00'), moment('2020-01-01 11:00')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 14:00'), moment('2020-01-01 18:00')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 20:00'), moment('2020-01-01 21:00')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 22:00'), moment('2020-01-01 23:00'))
];

let b = [
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 11:30'), moment('2020-01-01 13:00')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 17:00'), moment('2020-01-01 20:30')),
    moment.range(moment('2020-01-01 21:45'), moment('2020-01-01 23:15'))
];

let c = [];

b.forEach(range => {
    if (!a.includes(range))
        c.push(range)
})
```

Comment: Tried your code and received the error `TypeError: a.contains is not a function`

Comment: @Nyxynyx, I'm so sorry, here should be `includes`. Check edited code, please

Comment: Thank you, however `c` obtained from your solution is still not the desired result. Just edited the original question to compare `c` calculated by your code and the desired `c`.